# MongoDB insert speed trade-offs

Tags: python, json, mongodb, bson

*In short:* There is a huge difference in insert speeds when I keep a JSON object with many fields in a single, string field of MongoDB, or keep each field of the JSON object in its own MongoDB field. 1) Is this difference normal? 2) Are these insertion speeds typical?

I have many records each with a unique string id and 600 integer values. They are already represented as JSON objects in a file -- each document on a separate line. If I represent a MongoDB document as a collection of integer fields and put my unique id into the `_id` field of MongoDB, I can insert around **50 documents per second**. If I instead create a document with only two fields (`_id` for the unique string id, and `val` as a single string which keeps the entire JSON line of the record) I can insert around **100 documents per second**.

I am using the Python client and have tried doing batch inserts (e.g., 10, 100, 1000 at a time). The difference is always there. **Is this behavior expected?** I naively assumed that I wouldn't see a difference because MongoDB itself keeps the records as BSON and there really shouldn't be much difference between having 600 fields each with an integer or a single string which contains a JSON record which, in turn, keeps 600 integers.

Addendum: 1) I do the conversion from JSON to a dictionary in both cases, to make sure it's not affecting the speed measurement(i.e., `json.loads` and other stuff). In other words, in the single-field-with-JSON-string case, I do everything I do in the other case, but ignore the converted dictionary.

2) I also tried a dry-run, everything intact without any insert to MongoDB. I can process around 700-800 lines per second.

3)

```
a. db.test.stats() in single-line-single field case (i.e. fast case):
{
    "ns" : "tmp.test",
    "count" : 7999,
    "size" : 71262392,
    "avgObjSize" : 8908.91261407676,
    "storageSize" : 88751616,
    "numExtents" : 9,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "lastExtentSize" : 21742848,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "flags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 466944,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 466944
    },
    "ok" : 1
}

b. db.test.stats() (each column to a separate case; i.e., slow case):
{
    "ns" : "tmp.test",
    "count" : 7999,
    "size" : 85710500,
    "avgObjSize" : 10715.15189398675,
    "storageSize" : 107561984,
    "numExtents" : 9,
    "nindexes" : 1,
    "lastExtentSize" : 26091264,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "flags" : 1,
    "totalIndexSize" : 466944,
    "indexSizes" : {
        "_id_" : 466944
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: Is your time measurement including the time, in python, of converting the string to a dictionary before insert? What indexes do you have on your collection? With a little more detail, we might be able to help...

Comment: Yes it does, but I do the conversion in both cases, anyway. See my edit for extended reply.

Comment: What version of pymongo are you running?

Comment: It would also help if you can show the output of `db.yourcollection.stats()`, from the mongo shell.

Comment: One last thing -- please check that your pymongo version has the C extension installed and working, by `>>> pymongo.has_c()` at the Python interactive shell (should be `True`)

Comment: It's 2.0.1, C extensions are disabled, and stats() are given in the question. I corrected a measurement error, the one-field-per-JSON document reports 100 insertions per second (the previous 500 value was for a space-separated list of the integers without any column names!).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If possible, enable the C extensions, as they will provide a significant performance improvement. I think the difference in speed is due to the larger number of keys that must be serialized (by pure-Python code, since you have the extensions disabled) into the BSON document. With the C extensions enabled, this will be much faster (but must still be done), so I suspect you will still see a (very slight) difference in speed between the two approaches.

**Edit:** Note that when I say "enable the C extensions," I mean re-build pymongo, or use a pre-built binary for your platform that has the C modules built. You can see the available binary packages at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/2.0.1#downloads

Comment: With C extensions enabled (for which I needed to install python-dev), I get 500 insertions per second with each integer on a separate field. Thanks!

Comment: Out of curiosity, what distribution are you using? How did you install pymongo, with `easy_install` or `pip`?

Comment: Ubuntu Hardy, and I used easy_install. I remember some warnings about a missing python-dev during the installation, but I didn't pay attention to them at the time :)